# CollapsingToolbarLayout Showing padding bottom in ImageView

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

When using android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and android:adjustViewBounds="true" together for ImageView in CollapsingToolbarLayout its give padding to ImageView at bottom

and i am posting its answer to help this reference this issue solution to help others on github issue that i have raised a long time ago

Expected behavior:
[image]

Current behavior:
[image]

Layout XMl:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_bundle_detail_layout"
        layout="@layout/include_bundle_detail_layout" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.Base.AppBarLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimarySurface"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_bundleOfferImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:src="@drawable/playstore_feature_graphic"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_image_upper_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_black_transparent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.Base.Toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
   <style name="Widget.Base.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">?actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix that you need to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from root to every child view until the view that you want to show below the status bar and just set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" to those views you want to get auto padding according to status bar height so this will fix the padding issue on image view but now that black gradient act weird and being to the size of the toolbar to fix that i have manually set padding to gradient in code using window insets check code below for that

> Layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/base_model_detail_layout_include"
            layout="@layout/base_model_detail_layout_include" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimarySurface"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:statusBarScrim="?colorPrimarySurface"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_bundleOffer"
                style="@style/Widget.PNBO.BundleOfferDetailFragment.ImageView"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                tools:src="@drawable/playstore_feature_graphic"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_image_upper_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_black_transparent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                tools:visibility="visible" />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                style="@style/Widget.PNBO.BundleOfferDetailFragment.Toolbar" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Kotlin code

```
    private fun setUpSystemBars() {

        binding.root.apply {

            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this) { _, insets ->

                val top = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars()).top
                val height: Int

                binding.viewImageUpperGradient?.also {
                    height = it.layoutParams.height
                    it.layoutParams.height = height + top
                }

                insets
            }
        }
    }
```